# edit_text cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

I hit "Run" while doing the tutorial on Android.com in Eclipse, and I get "edit_text cannot be resolved or is not a field". Here is my code for MainActivity '

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.Tutorial.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
}


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage (View view){
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent=new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivityNewNew.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

And my second activity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivityNewNew extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Main_Activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="MainActivity" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

No idea what the issue is, but if you have any help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the import as mentioned by @Raghunandan, Clean your project. Check ui xmls some component  is , maybe, interfering with the ide while creating Resource file of your project.
EDIT: I see you have used android.R.id.home, that forces you to import android.R that simply makes any reference to R as a reference to android.R, wherever you have used R simply use YOURPACKAGENAME.R.Resourcename

Comment: Simply clean your project
and then replace any R.id reference while initialising your views with YOURPACKAGENAME.R.id

Comment: yep because this is the R(resource) file of your project. And android.R is the generic resource file in android package.

Comment: is Tutorial a class?? because R isn't a subclass of tutorial. most probably example is the package. so import example.R;

Comment: com.example.R, or just example.R?

Comment: Okay fill me up now I'm simultaneously reading the comments you are placing in the other answer. Is the id edit_message or edit_text. and if com.example.R cannot be resolved that simply means your ide isn;t building the R file on its own. You need to re check all the User Interface xml files that you have made. One of the views is causing a problem

Comment: is the id edit_text, or edit_message as you wrote in the above comment?

Comment: I honestly don't know. It -should- be edit_message. Where is edit_text?

Comment: Here is your answer, Remove android.R import from first class and change the line R.id.edit_text to R.id.edit_message

Comment: That's fine, but now I have activity_list_item unable to be resolved.

Comment: use android.R.activity_list_item for that reference

Comment: @coolbob5413 the error can be in any of the resource files. Its hard to post all those here and hard to look at everything. Pls fix the errors under resources files by looking at the console

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how.

Comment: sorry my bad, its android.R.layout.activity_list_item

Comment: @coolbob5413 well we are not your debuggers. We can point you in the right direction. The hint is look at the console.

Comment: another thing if this is your first app, I shall point you out at the fact that what you're doing is pointing the app to use the generic activity_list_item layout(hope, this is what you want) but if you want to use the layout where you have creted all these buttons in setContentView() use R.layout.Main_Activity

Comment: @KaranJ, I found it online, just (trying) to follow directions

Comment: yes this is the main layout that you've built. the edit text and the button is contained in the layout you have built. the activity_list_item layout does not. So to properly use your application you will have to set the proper layout and use the ids that you've mentioned in that layout. Otherwise referencing R.id will give you a definite hit but it won't work because then you will be referencing to an object that isn't even there in your view.

Comment: So I have to add "android:activity_list_item" in somewhere with my Main_Activity.xml?

Comment: I believe this is your first app try vogella tutorials, they're good for basics or video tutorials on youtube

Comment: No .xml is okay you need to change the reference R.layout.activity_list_item to R.layout.Main_Activity.

Comment: Okay, I do that in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below import

```
import android.R;
```

Comment: It remains the same issue, but now I have activity_list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field as well.

Comment: @coolbob5413 looking at the code further. I do not see anything wrong other than what i have mentioned

Comment: In line 24, MainActivity

Comment: Alright, I don't know how to do that, because I'm new to this. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @coolbob5413 `import yourpackagename.R;`. Also if you have any errors in resources files ie under res folder fix them clean and build

Comment: So, "com.example.Tutorial.R"?

Comment: @coolbob5413 `import com.example.Tutorial.R` and if you still have errors then you need to check resource files

Comment: @coolbob5413 then there are errors in your resource files need to fix them first then clean and build your proejct

Comment: So, do I display them here? How will I see an error?

Comment: @coolbob5413 what do you see in the console? should give you an hint

Comment: [2014-03-02 11:35:20 - Tutorial] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: @coolbob5413 that is one line now look at your xmls some thing is wrong in one of them. What is wrong i can't tell without seeing all of them. Look at the names given. check if you have closed tag or not.**Error in an XML file: aborting build**. indicates something is wrong

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>